# Scroll Infinito Genexus SD

Tags: genexus

Buenas, estoy necesitando implementar un scroll infinito, o sea que en la medida que el usuario hace scroll en una grilla que tiene "potencialmente" miles de ítems. Inicialmente tengo un SDT y es el que muestro en la grilla.

La idea es que:

1. El SDT cargue de a 20 desde la posición del cursor
2. Se muestren esos 20 en la grilla
3. Se guarde la posición en que quedo el cursor

Esto debería ser rápido. En la medida que el usuario hace scroll hacia abajo, se repite el ciclo 1, 2 y 3 hasta terminar. De manera de no sobrecargar a la grilla.

Lo mas parecido que encontré en el wiki es esto:

http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?21311,HowTo%3A+External+Services+%28Scenario2%29,

donde se definen variables count, Start (para decir cuantos cargar y desde que posición de la consulta cargar) y los sdt que cargan los valores. El tema es que no me queda claro como funciona.

Se carga en el LOAD pero en ningún lugar veo que se actualice el valor de la variable Start por lo tanto siempre estaría cargando los mismos 20 ítems.

Si alguien implemento algo así que pueda acercarme una explicación, algún indicio o un xpz bienvenido!!

Saludos y gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema con tener el *grid* basado en un **SDT**, es que esos *grids* no tienen un *data provider* asociado, se cargan a partir del *data provider* del contenedor.

Para poder usar paginado deberías basar el *grid* en variables, y programar usando las variables `&start` y `&count` en el evento `Load`.

Comment: gracias Marcos debe ser ese mi problema entonces. Voy a probar!